# Syntax Error When Following Pygame/Python Tutorial on youtube

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, pygame

I've just downloaded python 3.3.2 and `pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py3.3.msi`.
I have decided to try a few tutorials on youtube and see if they work.

I have tried thenewboston's 'Game Development Tutorial - 2 - Basic Pygame Program' to see if it works. It is supposed to produce a black background and a ball that is the mouse (or so i think). It comes up with a syntax error when i try to run it, if i delete it it just produces a black pygame window. Here is the code:

```
bgg="bg.jpg"
ball="ball.png"

import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((540,341),0,32)

background=pygame.image.load(bgg).convert()
mouse_c=pygame.image.load(ball).convert_alpha()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type ==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.blit(background), (0,0))
```

The `screen.blit(bakcgorund, (0,0))` command is the problem, when it comes up with the syntax error it highlights the second bracket on the furthest right of the command. If I delete it it just shows a black pygame window. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import * 
#about: pygame boilerplate

class GameMain():
    # handles intialization of game and graphics, as well as game loop
    done = False

    def __init__(self, width=800, height=600):
        """Initialize PyGame window.

        variables:
            width, height = screen width, height
            screen = main video surface, to draw on

            fps_max = framerate limit to the max fps
            limit_fps = boolean toggles capping FPS, to share cpu, or let it run free.
            now = current time in Milliseconds. ( 1000ms = 1second)
        """
        pygame.init()

        # save w, h, and screen
        self.width, self.height = width, height
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(( self.width, self.height ))
        pygame.display.set_caption( "pygame tutorial code" )        

        self.sprite_bg = pygame.image.load("bg.jpg").convert()
        self.sprite_ball = pygame.image.load("ball.png").convert_alpha()


    def main_loop(self):
        """Game() main loop."""
        while not self.done:
            self.handle_events()        
            self.update()
            self.draw()

    def draw(self):
        """draw screen"""
        self.screen.fill(Color('darkgrey'))

        # draw your stuff here. sprites, gui, etc....        
        self.screen.blit(self.sprite_bg, (0,0))
        self.screen.blit(self.sprite_ball, (100,100))


        pygame.display.flip()

    def update(self):
        """physics/move guys."""
        pass

    def handle_events(self):
        """handle events: keyboard, mouse, etc."""
        events = pygame.event.get()
        kmods = pygame.key.get_mods()

        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.done = True
            # event: keydown
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE: self.done = True

if __name__ == "__main__":         
    game = GameMain()
    game.main_loop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your parenthesis are unbalanced; there are 2 opening parenthesis, and 3 closing parenthesis; that is one closing parenthesis too many:

```
screen.blit(background), (0,0))
#     -----^    ------^    ---^
```

You probably want to remove the closing parenthesis after `background`:

```
screen.blit(background, (0,0))
```

Comment: There is still no ball after I have changed it. Is it a problem with the pictures or some other part of the code?- the pics were done in paint, the bg is black and the ball is a red ball with a black background.

Comment: Why don't you read the tutorial and see what you are supposed to do with `mouse_c`? All your code does right now is blit `background` at position 0, 0.. You don't do anything with the ball image apart from loading it and converting the alpha channel.

Comment: What I have is all he shows on the tutorial, what i've figured out is the background also doesn't appear, is it my python version or something? I do know pygame doesn't work as well in pytho version 3 as it does earlier ones

Comment: Also, can you recommend any tutorials that would be useful?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't looked into tutorials for pygame in ages.