# Code Only Produces Black Screen In Pygame Window

Tags: python, screen, pygame

I followed a tutorial and copied the code exactly, though it only produces a pygame window with a black screen. Here is the link to the code(exactly as i typed it out):

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/83308-introduction-to-pygame-part-1/

It is correct as in the tutorial, yet does not work. I am using python 3.3.2 and pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py3.3.msi.

Comment: well it works for me on 2.7 so it could be a compatibility issue do you not get any kind of error?

Comment: Nope no error. Maybe t is a compatibility error, pygame seems to be out of date compared to the python releases and does not keep up with compatibility. A shame really. I'll try 2.7, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Nope, just a window, rather annoying.

Comment: that's interesting let me take another look just put the exact code youre running i know you copied it but maybe something is different better safe than sorry

Comment: Does this code run? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17767758/341744 And is the image in the right folder?

Comment: Yes it works, it produces the ball on the screen. Thankyou for your help as the overall aim was to produce an image