# Confused at why PyGame display's a black screen

Tags: python, screen, pygame

So before I decided to ask this question I did a little research to see what my problem was and came across this: [Code Only Produces Black Screen In Pygame Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767315/code-only-produces-black-screen-in-pygame-window) However this is not all that helpful as I haven't got the same issue as this person. I for sure know that my PyGame is not outdated or anything like that as I had a previous version of my code working.

Every time I run the code I end up getting a black screen.

Here is my code (A bit long sorry):

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)

objs = []

MAIN_BUTTON = 1

class Pane():

    def __init__(self):
        self.Screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,600), 0, 32)
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 25)

    def drawPane(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane1(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane2(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane3(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane4(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane5(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane6(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane7(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane8(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane9(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)

class Screen():

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 25)
        pygame.display.set_caption('Box Test')
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,600), 0, 32)
        self.screen.fill((white))
        pygame.display.update()
        numberOfPanes = 0
        self.NoOfPanes = numberOfPanes

    def addPane(self, textToDisplay):
        myPane = Pane()
        myPane.drawPane(textToDisplay)

    def clearScreen(self):
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,400), 0, 32)
        self.screen.fill((white))
        pygame.display.update()

    def mousePosition(self):
        global clickPos
        global releasePos
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == MAIN_BUTTON:
                self.Pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                return MAIN_BUTTON
            else:
                return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Pan3 = Screen()
    Pan3.addPane("hello")
    Pan3.mousePosition()
    pygame.display.update()
    while True:
        ev = pygame.event.get()
        for event in ev:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                posx,posy = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                print(posx)
                print(posy)


        for event in pygame.event.get():        
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit(); sys.exit();
```

So I am basically trying to display the panes (well one for now) from `**class Pane()**` in `**class Screen()**` however like I said before when I run the code I get a black screen. But for some reason the mouse co-ordinate tracker still works. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is your code organization.

You have tree times `pygame.display.set_mode()`. Every time you call `pygame.display.set_mode()` you destroy previous `screen`, create new `screen` and new screen is always black.

You should create `screen` only once and send it to other class as parameter.

```
def addPane(self, textToDisplay):
    myPane = Pane(self.screen) # send screen to Pane
    myPane.drawPane(textToDisplay)

# ...

class Pane():

    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.Screen = screen # get screen
```

And remove `pygame.display.set_mode()` from `clear()` function - use one screen to the end of the program.

Now I can see your pane with "hello"

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I have now solved my problem. (aha novice error).
So in the `__init__(self)` area within `class Pane()` I added the line `self.Screen.fill((white))` to make it look like this:

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.Screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,600), 0, 32)
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 25)
        self.Screen.fill((white))
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to solve the problem but it works. So that's good. However if you think that this isn't a good way to solve the problem then by all means teach me of a better way to solve my problem.