# why are both panes not being displayed in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pane

I'm confused at why when I call on two different panes they won't both display on the same screen. It is either one or the other. Can someone please help me by telling me why this is the case and also possibly show me how to fix the problem to be able to display both panes on the screen.

Here's the full code:

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)

objs = []

MAIN_BUTTON = 1

class Pane():

    def __init__(self):
        self.Screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,600), 0, 32)
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 25)
        self.Screen.fill((white))
        pygame.display.update()

    def drawPane(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (75, 135))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (0, 100, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane1(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (200, 300, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane2(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (400, 500, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane3(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (600, 75, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane4(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (800, 75, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane5(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane6(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane7(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane8(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane9(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)

class Screen():

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption('Box Test')
        numberOfPanes = 0
        self.NoOfPanes = numberOfPanes

    def addPane(self, textToDisplay):
        myPane = Pane()
        myPane.drawPane(textToDisplay)

    def addPane1(self, textToDisplay):
        myPane = Pane()
        myPane.drawPane1(textToDisplay)

    def addPane2(self, textToDisplay):
        myPane = Pane()
        myPane.drawPane2(textToDisplay)

    def addPane3(self, textToDisplay):
        myPane = Pane()
        myPane.drawPane3(textToDisplay)

    def addPane4(self, textToDisplay):
        myPane = Pane()
        myPane.drawPane4(textToDisplay)

    def addPane5(self, textToDisplay):
        myPane = Pane()
        myPane.drawPane5(textToDisplay)

    def addPane6(self, textToDisplay):
        myPane = Pane()
        myPane.drawPane6(textToDisplay)

    def addPane7(self, textToDisplay):
        myPane = Pane()
        myPane.drawPane7(textToDisplay)

    def addPane8(self, textToDisplay):
        myPane = Pane()
        myPane.drawPane8(textToDisplay)

    def addPane9(self, textToDisplay):
        myPane = Pane()
        myPane.drawPane9(textToDisplay)

    def clearScreen(self):
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,400), 0, 32)
        self.screen.fill((white))
        pygame.display.update()

    def mousePosition(self):
        global clickPos
        global releasePos
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == MAIN_BUTTON:
                self.Pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                return MAIN_BUTTON
            else:
                return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Pan3 = Screen()
    Pan3.addPane("hello")
    Pan3.addPane1("b")
    Pan3.mousePosition()
    pygame.display.update()
    while True:
        ev = pygame.event.get()
        for event in ev:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                posx,posy = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                if (posx >=175 or posx <=375) and (posy >=75 or posy <= 175):
                    print("bob")
                else:
                    print("error")


        for event in pygame.event.get():        
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit(); sys.exit();
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank-you.

Answer (score 1):

Pygame is essentially a wrapper for the SDL, and support for multiple displays and windows (what you call *"Panes"*) was added in version 2.0 (launched aug 2013). Unfortunately, as far as I know the last version of Pygame was 1.9.1, and it was launched on august 2009 so there's no support for the newest features.

Therefore, I'm afraid what you're trying to do is not possible using Pygame. However you should check [PySDL2](http://pysdl2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which seems to be actively developed and up to date with the latest additions of SDL.

Comment: Thank-you for your respone. I shall look in to it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `pygame.display.set_mode()` only once.

See my answer to your question [Confused at why PyGame display's a black screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19961529/1832058)

---

Full working code.

I move event loop into class because it use less CPU.

I also add `clock` to make 12 FPS - if you will make animation you can change it to 25 FPS or more.

I move other things into class and I changed its name to `Application` because it is how code should be organized

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)

objs = []

MAIN_BUTTON = 1

class Pane():

    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.Screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,600), 0, 32)
        self.Screen = screen #pygame.display.set_mode((1000,600), 0, 32)
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 25)
        self.Screen.fill((white))
        pygame.display.update()

    def drawPane(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (75, 135))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (0, 100, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane1(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (200, 300, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane2(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (400, 500, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane3(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (600, 75, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane4(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (800, 75, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane5(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane6(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane7(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane8(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)

    def drawPane9(self, textToDisplay):
        self.Screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.Screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)

class Application():

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption('Box Test')
        self.Screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,600), 0, 32)

        numberOfPanes = 0
        self.NoOfPanes = numberOfPanes

        self.addPane("hello")
        self.addPane1("b")
        self.mousePosition()
        pygame.display.update()


    def addPane(self, textToDisplay):
        myPane = Pane(self.Screen )
        myPane.drawPane(textToDisplay)

    def addPane1(self, textToDisplay):
        myPane = Pane(self.Screen )
        myPane.drawPane1(textToDisplay)

    def addPane2(self, textToDisplay):
        myPane = Pane(self.Screen )
        myPane.drawPane2(textToDisplay)

    def addPane3(self, textToDisplay):
        myPane = Pane(self.Screen )
        myPane.drawPane3(textToDisplay)

    def addPane4(self, textToDisplay):
        myPane = Pane(self.Screen )
        myPane.drawPane4(textToDisplay)

    def addPane5(self, textToDisplay):
        myPane = Pane(self.Screen )
        myPane.drawPane5(textToDisplay)

    def addPane6(self, textToDisplay):
        myPane = Pane(self.Screen )
        myPane.drawPane6(textToDisplay)

    def addPane7(self, textToDisplay):
        myPane = Pane(self.Screen )
        myPane.drawPane7(textToDisplay)

    def addPane8(self, textToDisplay):
        myPane = Pane(self.Screen )
        myPane.drawPane8(textToDisplay)

    def addPane9(self, textToDisplay):
        myPane = Pane(self.Screen )
        myPane.drawPane9(textToDisplay)

    def clearScreen(self):
        self.screen.fill((white))
        pygame.display.update()

    def mousePosition(self):
        global clickPos
        global releasePos
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == MAIN_BUTTON:
                self.Pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                return MAIN_BUTTON
            else:
                return False

    def run(self):
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        while True:
            # --- events ---
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    posx,posy = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    if (175 <= posx <= 375) and (75 <= posy <= 175):
                        print("bob")
                    else:
                        print("error")

            # --- FPS ---
            clock.tick(12) # 12 FPS (Frames Per Second)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().run()
```

**EDIT:**

You should test mouse positon in this way to make it works:

```
if (175 <= posx <= 375) and (75 <= posy <= 175):
    print("bob")
else:
    print("error")
```

Comment: Thank you it is better that way to be fair aha.